# Recompile with Xlint:unchecked for details

Tags: animation, canvas, javafx, event-handling

I made a program that creates a rectangle in a canvas, and is moved by using an event handler for the keyboard's arrow keys. There is also a choice box with options 1 -5 to express the speed selected. A speed of 1 shows that the rectangle moves 1 pixel per key press, a speed of 2 shows that the rectangle moves 2 pixels per key press, and so on. My code compiles and runs correctly in netbeans, however I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong when I try to compile it in PuTTY.

The error I first received was

```
        Note: AnimatedRectangle.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
        Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

So I recompiled with -Xlint, and got the following output:

```
         AnimatedRectangle.java:71: warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to 
         ChoiceBox(ObservableList<T>) as a member of the raw type ChoiceBox
                cb = new ChoiceBox(FXCollections.observableArrayList (
         where T is a type variable:
         T extends Object declared in class ChoiceBox
         AnimatedRectangle.java:75: warning [unchecked] unchecked call to
         setValue(T) as a member of the raw type ChoiceBox
                 cb.setValue("1");
         where T is a type variable:
         T extends Object declared in class ChoiceBox
         2 warnings
```

This is my entire code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections; 
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class AnimatedRectangle extends Application {

Group root;
Canvas canvas;
Scene scene;
GraphicsContext gc;
ChoiceBox cb;
String cbInput;
int speed;
int x, y, width, height;
int n = x + 1;
String userInput;



@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    //declare rectangle variables
    width = 100;
    height = 50;
    y = 150;
    x = 150;
    n = x + 1;

    //declare a new group and a new canvas
    root = new Group();
    canvas = new Canvas(400, 400);

    //set the scene and make the background color white
    scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400, Color.WHITE);

    //create a 2D graphics context
    gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();

    //create a green rectangle
    gc.setFill(Color.GREEN);
    gc.fillRect(150, 150, 100, 50);

    //create a choice box with options 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5
    cb = new ChoiceBox(FXCollections.observableArrayList(
    "1","2","3","4","5"));

    //set the pre-determined value to 1
    cb.setValue("1");

    //add the canvas and the choice box to the group
    root.getChildren().add(canvas);
    root.getChildren().add(cb);

    //add an event handler to the group. 
    //This event handler will first decide which choice box
    //is selected, and according to that, a series of events will occur.
    //The rectangle will either move right or left depending on
    //which key is pressed. The choice box options determine the
    //speed in which the rectangle will move. 1 meaning 1 pixel per move,
    //and 5 meaning 5 pixels per move, and so on.
    root.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>(){
        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent event){

            userInput = cb.getValue().toString();

            if (userInput == "1"){
                switch (event.getCode()){
                    case RIGHT: //gc.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
                                gc.clearRect(x, y, width, height);
                                gc.fillRect(n+1, y, width, height);
                                x = n + 1;
                                n++;
                                break;

                    case LEFT:  gc.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
                                gc.clearRect(x, y, width, height);
                                gc.fillRect(n-1, y, width, height);
                                x = n - 1;
                                n--;  
                                break;
                }
            }

            if (userInput == "2"){
                switch (event.getCode()){
                    case RIGHT: gc.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
                                gc.clearRect(x, y, width, height);
                                gc.fillRect(n+2, y, width, height);
                                x = n + 2;
                                n = n + 2;
                                break;

                    case LEFT:  gc.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
                                gc.clearRect(x, y, width, height);
                                gc.fillRect(n-2, y, width, height);
                                x = n - 2;
                                n = n - 2;
                                break;
                }
            }
            if (userInput == "3"){
                switch (event.getCode()){
                    case RIGHT: gc.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
                                gc.clearRect(x, y, width, height);
                                gc.fillRect(n+3, y, width, height);
                                x = n + 3;
                                n = n + 3;
                                break;

                    case LEFT:  gc.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
                                gc.clearRect(x, y, width, height);
                                gc.fillRect(n-3, y, width, height);
                                x = n - 3;
                                n = n - 3; 
                                break;
                }
            }
            if (userInput == "4"){
                switch (event.getCode()){
                    case RIGHT: gc.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
                                gc.clearRect(x, y, width, height);
                                gc.fillRect(n+4, y, width, height);
                                x = n + 4;
                                n = n + 4;
                                break;

                    case LEFT:  gc.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
                                gc.clearRect(x, y, width, height);
                                gc.fillRect(n-4, y, width, height);
                                x = n - 4;
                                n = n - 4;  
                                break;
                }
            }
            if (userInput == "5"){
                switch (event.getCode()){
                    case RIGHT: gc.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
                                gc.clearRect(x, y, width, height);
                                gc.fillRect(n+5, y, width, height);
                                x = n + 5;
                                n = n + 5;
                                break;

                    case LEFT:  gc.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
                                gc.clearRect(x, y, width, height);
                                gc.fillRect(n-5, y, width, height);
                                x = n - 5;
                                n = n -5;  
                                break;
                }
            }
        }
    });

    //set the title & scene of the stage
    primaryStage.setTitle("Move rectangle");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();


}

//the main class
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

}
```

I can really use all the help I can get! If you see an error in my code, please comment and let me know what you think! Thank you!

Comment: Oops! I actually figured it out. I ended up declaring the cb as ChoiceBox<String> cb; and in my code, instead of cb = new ChoiceBox(FXCollections.observableArrayList("1","2","3","4","5"));, I put cb = new ChoiceBox<String>(FXCollections.observableArrayList("1","2","3","4","5"));. I also changed cb.setValue("1") to cb.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();

Comment: It's fine to answer your own question on SO, so post that as an answer. It will help others who have the same question. You might want to read further on this topic: start [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html)